# PHP Overlay GIF on JPEG

Tags: php, gd

At the moment I am generating a barcode using Shay Anderson's class (http://www.shayanderson.com/php/php-barcode-generator-class-code-39.htm) and I am able to successfully display the generated barcode in the browser as follows:

```
$bc = new PrintBarcode('DARP CODE');
$bc->drawVoucher();
$src = $bc->getVoucher();

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($src);
```

but now I am trying to modify my script to overlay the barcode on top of another image to create a voucher but I can't seem to get it to work, I just get the broken image icon in Chrome and the following warning in the console:

`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg`

```
$bc = new PrintBarcode('DARP CODE');
$bc->drawVoucher();
$src = $bc->getVoucher();

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// create actual voucher with barcode overlayed on voucher background 
$bg  = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/voucher.jpg');

imagecopymerge($bg, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($bg), imagesy($bg), 75);

imagejpeg($bg, null, 100);

imagedestroy($bg);
```

Error reporting is on and I'm getting no wanrings, notices or fatal errors. Any help appreciated.

The only thing I can think of is that from the docs of the barcode class, it generates the barcode as a gif so not sure if I am missing a few steps.

Comment: Can you see the headers sent? Your browser might have a plugin for that. Maybe an error occures and therefore does send a wrong header or something.

Comment: `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg` means you are outputting something that is not image data before your image output - probably some stray HTML or the output of e.g. `var_dump()`, but possibly just white space. Download the file from the URL, save it to you hard drive and inspect the bytes of it, you will find data at the start of the file that should not be there. Once you know what output is being created that shouldn't be, you just need to go through the code until you track it down.

Comment: in my main application I will be generating it through AJAX so just checked the response header and it says `Content-Type:text/html` but not sure that's the problem as when I just do the barcode itself it's the same header and it works, I think that just might be because the dataype parameter in my ajax request is 'html' though.

Comment: @DaveRandom, thanks but I honestly can't see any erroneous output, plus it's fine with just the barcode, it's when I try the overlaying part that it stops working :/

Comment: @martincarlin87 There's a pretty good chance that there's an error/warning message in there then, have you tried simply putting `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` at the top of your script? (this probably won't make the image display correctly but I would expect the console warning to disappear/be replaced by another message) - are you able to make the data of the file produced by your script available for download?

Comment: Hi Dave, I can give you the link but I can't find an email address for you, you could email me and I will reply? Either that or take the question to chat but I can't seem to find the option....

Comment: @martincarlin87 http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Comment: @martincarlin87 If you're interested, [here](https://github.com/DaveRandom/Code39) is my re-working of the Code 39 generation code you are using above.

Comment: @DaveRandom very cool Dave, well done and thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was to do with the image I was using as the basis of the merge wasn't quite right so I re-converted it from a png to jpg properly (first time I downloaded the png I simply did a save as all files to jpeg) using photoshop and it was fine, to clarify, here's the code:

```
$bc = new PrintBarcode('DARP CODE');
$bc->drawVoucher();
$src = $bc->getVoucher();

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$bg  = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/voucher.jpg');

imagecopymerge($bg, $src, 40, 380, 0, 0, imagesx($bg), imagesy($bg), 100);

imagejpeg($bg, null, 100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($bg);
```